# Refactor reading elements in an XML file - C#

Tags: c#, xml, refactoring

Can I refactor the following piece of code reading elements in an XML file:

```
if (!(xmlDoc.Element("Element1").Element("Element2").Element("Element3").Element("Element4").Element("Element5").Element("Element6") == null))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `XPath` expression for find element what you want, this code who you submited can easly throw unexpected `NullReferenceException` who probably you don't want `catch`.

Something like this:

```
if (xPath.evaluate("count(/Element1/Element2/Element3/Element4)", xmlDoc) > 0)
{
}
```

PS.
Why you negating expression of `== null`? Better readable and maintainable is `!= null` without negation and trailing `()` in your boolean expression.

Comment: What object type did you use to initialize the xPath variable?